# Android - programatically changing the row layout of a custom listView row fails when focus is requested on its edittext child

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

Sorry for the long title.

I have an android application which shows a custom listView with 5 TextView columns. When the user clicks a row, I change the layout to have 3 TextViews and 2 EditTexts. I have different layout files for both of them. Everything worked fine initially, the row layout changes properly and I am able to click on the EditText and input values. However, I want either of the 2 EditText to automatically gain focus based on what is clicked. I already have a working code for this. My problem is that programatically requesting `requestFocus()` seems to block the part where I change the row layout with the new view.

Here is the code that changes my row layout, it works fine without the `requestFocus()` line:

```
private void changeLayout(final View view){

    //get views from old row layout
    TextView textViewQuantity = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.qtyInput);
    TextView textViewDiscountReq = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.discInput);
    TextView textViewName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.dialogItemName);
    TextView textViewPrice = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.price);
    TextView textViewDiscount = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.discount);

    //store values in strings
    String itemName = textViewName.getText().toString();
    String itemPrice = textViewPrice.getText().toString();
    String itemDiscount = textViewDiscount.getText().toString();
    String itemQty = textViewQuantity.getText().toString();
    String itemDisc = textViewDiscountReq.getText().toString();

    //set the view to gone
    textViewQuantity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    textViewDiscountReq.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    textViewName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    textViewPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    textViewDiscount.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //get the old layout
    LinearLayout ll_inflate = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.search_result_layout);   

    //get the inflate/new view
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.search_result_inflate, null);

    //get the views in the new view, populate them
    TextView newName = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.dialogItemName);
    newName.setText(itemName);

    TextView newDiscount = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.discount);
    newDiscount.setText(itemDiscount);

    TextView newPrice = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.price);
    newPrice.setText(itemPrice);

    qtyIn = (EditText)child.findViewById(R.id.qtyInputSearchResult);
    qtyIn.setText(itemQty);
    qtyIn.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {filter});

    discIn = (EditText)child.findViewById(R.id.discInputSearchResult);
    discIn.setText(itemDisc);

    //show new layout
    ll_inflate.removeAllViews();
    ll_inflate.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    ll_inflate.addView(child);

    //request focus here
    if(focusTarget == 1){
        Log.d("hello", "focus target is 1 " );
        qtyIn.setFocusable(true);
        qtyIn.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        qtyIn.requestFocus();
    }
    else if(focusTarget == 2){
        Log.d("hello", "focus target is 2 " );
        discIn.requestFocus();
    }

    Log.d("hello", "focus state qtyIn = " + qtyIn.isFocused());
    Log.d("hello", "focus state discIn = " + discIn.isFocused());
}
```

The interesting part is that the Log shows the proper values, it says the proper focus status according to what I want. However, the `ll_inflate.addView(child);` line does not work at all!

Does anyone know what happened here? I'm really confused as to why the layout didn't change but the lines *after* the `.addView()` line executed. Another weird thing is how `requestFocus();` prevents the view from changing.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this in wrong way. You should have two type of view in list, one for show data and one for edit it.
First set view type count

> final int TYPE_EDIT =0,TYPE_VIEW =1;//**EDIT 7/9/016** type need to be start from 0

```
public int getViewTypeCount (){
 return 2;
}
public int getItemViewType (int position){
  //return type as needed. simple if you add int for this in data model
}
```

And inside **getView**

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    int type = getItemViewType ();
    if(null==convertView){
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(type ==TYPE_EDIT){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowEditlayout, parent, false);
        }else{
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        }
    }   
}
```

Do the changes in list data on edit button click and call **notifydatasetchanged** on adapter